# Jersey 2.5 and WADL generation : HTTP 404

Tags: jersey, http-status-code-404, wadl

When I access the WADL with the following URL: 
    `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/application.wadl`
Tomcat responds HTTP 404.

My configuration is :
- Tomcat 7
- Jersey 2.5.1
- Jackson 2.3.0
- Spring 3.2.5

I would like to know what to do so that Jeresy generates the WADL file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem :

My servlet mapping is :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp-web-service-rest-v0</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/wsrest/v0/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then the WADL URL is :

`http://localhost:8080/MyApp/wsrest/v0/application.wadl`

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I made the same mistake you did and assumed it was going to be at `context-root`.